# I have a problem with try to get a property of a column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I already know that the problem with this question that I will explain is similar to these other questions.

[Trying to get property of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547972/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)

[Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022315/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-laravel-5-4)

[Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351893/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-laravel-5-5)

But my problem is not the exactly the same problem of those questions or a another similar question.

I have a website about Sale of Cars where I show a table with all customers and the number of cars that each customer has bought, when I click on the button 'See more details...' the web page redirects to another web page that show more details about the selected customer.

On that webpage I have another table that shows the number of cars, the date, the model and the car's brand, that the customer has purchased, and a button that you can add a new car that the customer has bought.

> *NOTE:I enter in this website as an ADMIN.*

When I click on this button to add new cars. I get this error.

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>    Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\car- 
>    shopping\resources\views\CarShop\ShowCustomerCarsDetails.blade.php)

The line of code that this message of mistake emphasizes is:

```
<td>{{$customer->id}}</td>
```

This is the Table of customer details that appears after I clicked the button *(says: see more details...)* on the previous page. Before the page ShowCustomerCarDetails.blade.php.

```
<!--ShowCustomerCarDetails.blade.php-->

<tbody> 
  <tr>


    <td>{{$customer->id}}</td> <!--THIS LINE-->


    <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$customer->address}}</td>
    <td>{{$customer->phoneNumber}}</td>

        @if($car->id == $customer->car_id)
            <td>{{$car->model}}</td>
        @endif           
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

> *NOTE:* The previous page of **'ShowCustomerCarDetails.blade.php'** is called, **'ShowCustomersAndCars_index.blade.php'** On this webpage I have a table that shows all customers and the number of cars that they have bought, is in this page that I have a button called *'See more details...'* that redirect to **'ShowCustomerCarDetails.blade.php'**.

And this is the body of the table car that the customer has bought.

```
<!--At the end of the website 
ShowCustomerCarDetails.blade.php -->

<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>CAR NAME</th>
     <th>CAR MODEL</th>
     <th>CAR PRICE</th>
     <th>CAR YEAR</th>
     <th>PURCHASE DATE</th>
     <th>OWNER</th>
    </tr>

</thead>

<tbody>
    @foreach($date as $carDateBuy)
        @if($customer->id == $carDateBuy->customer_id)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$car->name}}</td>             
                <td>{{$car->model}}</td>
                <td>{{$car->price}}</td>
                <td>{{$car->year}}</td>
                <td>{{$carDateBuy->date}}</td>
                <td>{{$carDateBuy->customer_name}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

> *NOTE: The Table dates, it fills automatically with customer's information when a customer buys a car.*

And the button to add new cars in the same web page.

```
<div>
  <a href="{{route('NewCars')}}">
    <input type="button" name="AddCars" value="ADD NEW CAR">
  </a>
</div>
```

And the route in **web.php**

```
Route::get('ListCustomersCar/NewCars',['as' => 'NewCars', 'uses' => 'CustomerCarController@createNewCars']);
```

The **CustomerCarController** method `createNewCars()`:

```
public function createNewCars(){

  return view('customer.NewCars');
}
```

For more details I add the tables and his relations:

[Picture1_Car-Customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZMWP.png)

[Picture2_Customer-Date1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjlFP.png)

[Picture3_Customer-Date2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs7Eq.png)

What I'm doing wrong in my website? If I'm missing something, I will update this question. Thanks!

Comment: you aren't returning anything from the controller except a view. without any variables to use in the blade file, how do you expect it to work?

Comment: what does your $customer contain ?  do a print_r($customer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is in

> ShowCustomerCarDetails.blade.php

then the problem is with the controller (let's call this controller as `CustomerController.php` for now) and the function (as `showCustomerCarDetails()`) **which is returning the above view file**.

So, the possible solution would be to check the controller `CustomerController.php` and the function `showCustomerCarDetails()`.
Please find below a checklist for debugging the problem,

1. At first, please check if you are getting the `$customer` variable properly in the `showCustomerCarDetails` function, by dumping it `dd($customer)`. Here, I am assuming that you know how to get the `$customer` variable from the Customer model. It's simple like `$customer=Customer::findOrFail($id)`, the `$id` parameter is the one that was passed via the URL to the controller and the function.
2. Now if you are getting the customer data from the database, then send this variable that is `$customer` along with the view file using your preferred method,
   like for example `return view('CarShop.ShowCustomerCarsDetails', compact($customer))`

I hope it solves the problem and in case of any doubt please don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: It's not work. I did this in the method `showNewCars` I called this method like that.                                                                                                              `public function showNewCars($id){

    $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

    dd($customer); //This line is ok?
    
    return view('customer.NewCars', compact($customer));
  
  }`

Comment: Yes, it's correct after running the above code what are you getting when you hit the url? Aren't you getting the Customer model?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have just noticed. The method is not `show` I try to create new Cars for the table Cars, this is the reason that the button is called _Add new Cars_. The method that I use is `create` I called this method **createNewCars** and I created the corresponding route in **web.php**. But the problem is not solved yet. :/

Comment: Finally I solved my problem, thanks!! I did a new controller, and I created new routes, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass to the `view()` function an array with the variables that your view will use, e.g.:

```
return view('customer.newCars', 
    [
        'customer' => $customer,
        'car' => $car,
        ...
    ]
);
```

If you want to pass eloquent objects, try:

```
return view('customer.newCars', compact($customer, $car, ...));
```

Comment: The problem persists after I returned the view with these parameters, what can I do?

Comment: It's not work, What might be the problem?, The line of code is the same. `<td>{{$customer->id}}</td> ` this is the line that the website shows me as an error.